# Advice neaed: a best way to write binary data to pipe

Tags: c#, html, memory, pipe

I need a way to write data with minimum allocations, as it possible when read from ReadOnlySequence.

A best way that I found is [SpanWriter](https://dotnet.github.io/dotNext/api/DotNext.Buffers.SpanWriter-1.html) from side library.

But probably some one knows a better standard solution.

```
using System.IO.Pipelines

namespace WriteSample
{
    public async Task Write()
    {
        var pipe = new Pipe();

        var memory = pipe.Writer.GetMemory(2048);
        
        var writer = new Writer???(memory.Span);

        writer.Write((byte)0xFF);
        writer.Write((long)12345);
        writer.WriteBigEndian((long)12345);

        await pipe.Writer.FlushAsync()

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you're not calling `pipe.Writer.Advance(x)`?

Answer (score 2):

The way provided by the runtime is [using `BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-6.0):

```
var span = memory.Span;
span[0] = 0xFF;
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt64LittleEndian(span.Slice(1), 12345);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt64BigEndian(span.Slice(9), 12345);
```

This does have the disadvantage of meaning you need to keep track of where in the span you've written to so far, unlike e.g. `BinaryWriter`. I don't know of any types in the runtime to help with this, so you'll probably have to write your own, if you care.

Something like:

```
public ref struct SpanWriter
{
    private Span<byte> span;    
    public SpanWriter(Span<byte> span) => this.span = span;
    
    public void WriteInt64BigEndian(long value)
    {
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt64BigEndian(span, value);
        span = span.Slice(8);
    }
}
```